# Unable to make a file auto-download from an FTP server when script is run

Tags: php, javascript, html, ftp

I am attempting to write a PHP page that takes the GET variable which is a filename within the FTP and download it. However, it does not seem to work. The Function itself (ftp_get) is returning as TRUE as the echo statement is being run, however nothing else happens and there is no errors in console.

```
<?php  
$file = $_GET['file'];

$ftp_server = "127.0.0.1";
$ftp_user_name = "user";
$ftp_user_pass = "pass";
// set up a connection or die
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if (ftp_get($conn_id, $file, $file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

?>
```

Ideally, I would simply link them to:  ftp://example.com/TestFile.txt  and it would download the file for them, however, it only shows them the contents of the file in their browser rather than downloading it.

I've gone through the PHP Manual site reading the FTP functions and I do believe ftp_get is the correct one I'm suppose to be using.

Is there potentially an easier way of doing this, or is it just something I'm overlooking?

Comment: From the manual: "ftp_get() retrieves a remote file from the FTP server, and saves it into a local file." Local means the machine running PHP, not the client's desktop machine. I don't know if there's a method simpler than reading the saved file and outputting it to the user.

Comment: is `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` on?

Comment: @Jeffman There is no way to simply get a file from an FTP to download onto the user's PC? It doesn't seem like that farfetched of a concept.

Comment: @JohnnyJS Those are on yes, no errors. It is simply writing the file to the directory where the script is being run, but I want the end user to have it downloaded onto THEIR PC not the FTP's PC.

Comment: Can you please try : `echo file_get_contents(ftp_get($conn_id, $file, $file, FTP_BINARY));` ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two (or maybe more) ways you can do this. You could store a copy of the file on your server like you do with ftp_get and send it to the user afterwards. Or you could download it every time.

Now you can do this using ftp commands, but there is a quicker way using [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).
Following the first example from the `readfile` documentation:

```
// Save the file as a url
$file = "ftp://{$ftp_user_name}:{$ftp_user_pass}@{$ftp_server}" . $_GET['file'];

// Set the appropriate headers for a file transfer
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
// and send them
ob_clean();
flush();

// Send the file
readfile($file);
```

This will simply fetch the file and forward it's contents to the user. And the header will make the browser save the file as a download.

And you could take this even further. Let's say you save this in a file called script.php in a directory accessible to the user via `http://example.com/ftp/`. If you are using apache2 and have mod_rewrite enabled you can create a `.htaccess` file in this directory containing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ script.php?file=$1 [L]
```

When the user navigates to `http://exmaple.com/ftp/README.md` your script.php file will be called with `$_GET['file']` equal to `/README.md` and the file from `ftp://user:pass@ftp.example.com/README.md` will be *downloaded* on his computer.